# Best suited algorithm for prediction of purchase or no purchase based on click stream data

Tags: machine-learning

Could anyone please suggest the best suited model to be used for the prediction if a customer who has visited the website will buy a product based on the click stream data.Also,it would be great if you could provide necessary resources to analyse the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the following algo/repositories:
https://github.com/aksnzhy/xlearn/blob/master/README.md

"xLearn can be used for solving large-scale machine learning problems. First, xLearn supports out-of-core training, which can handle very large data (TB) by just leveraging the disk of a PC. In addition, xLearn supports distributed training, which scales beyond billions of example across many machines by using the parameter server framework."

https://github.com/fmfn/FTRLp/blob/master/README.md

From the last one description:

"More over this method is very efficient at obtaining sparsity and has proven to perform very well in massive Click-Through-Rate prediction tasks."

Answer (score -1):

Always remember that every machine learning problem is unique in itself. No two datasets can be the same. One model might give a better result on your performance measure on one problem but may give the worst result on some other problem.

Since you mentioned that you need a $0/1$ prediction, you might want to play around with supervised learning algorithms. Some of the popular ones are K Nearest Neighbors, Naive Bayes, Random Forests, SVM, Logistic Regression, Neural Networks (or if you have enough computation resources you might also want to try out Deep Neural Networks).

Visualize the data the data and find out if it is linearly separable on the given features. If yes, bingo! Otherwise, try out to project features in some high dimensional space and then apply the models.